# Saving an animation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have rendered 20 seconds animation in matplotlib.

```py
n = 2000
def update(curr):
    curr = curr*10
    if curr == n:
        a.event_source.stop()
    t = curr / 100
    plt.cla()
    rho_ = [2/(pi*(hbar**2)) * math.cos((((p1 - p2)*x)/(2*hbar)) + (((E1 - E2)*t)/(2*hbar)))**2 for x in x]
    plt.plot(x, rho_)
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
    plt.gca().set(yticklabels=[])
    plt.gca().tick_params(left=False)
    plt.gca().set_xlabel("X")
    plt.gca().set_title("Time evolution of probability density")
    plt.annotate(s = f"t = {t}s", xy = (0.9, 0.9), xycoords="figure fraction", fontsize=10)
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3.5))
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=50)
```

To save this animation I'm using

```py
a.save("probability_density_animation.avi")
```

Each time I run this code, it only saves the first five seconds of the animation. How do I save whole 20 seconds of the animation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line_ani.save('lines.mp4', writer=writer)` for more information check out https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/basic_example_writer_sgskip.html